# Can I create conditional query to skip an AND condition if the parameter value is NULL using ADO.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I am pretty new in **C#** and **.NET** (I came from Java EE environment) and I have the following doubt about how to use **ADO.NET** to create SQL query that allows condition on the parameters.

So basically in my project I have a class where I have the queries declared as static string variables, something like this:

```
public static class PROT_UTENTI
{

    public static string SELECT_USERS_FROM_AOO =
        @"SELECT *
            FROM PROT_UTENTI
            WHERE [SiglaAOO] = @SiglaAOO
            AND [Notifica] = @Notifica";

    ...............................................................
    ...............................................................
    ...............................................................
}
```

As you can see in the previous code I have a query represented by the **SELECT_USERS_FROM_AOO** that take 2 parameters **@SiglaAOO** and **@Notifica**.

My doubt is: **@Notifica** can be **null**. If this parameter value is null I want to skipe this **AND** condition.

ADO.NET allow to do it in some way?

Comment: `([Notifica] = @Notifica or @Notifica is null)`?

Comment: You have hardcoded the query text. So it is not possible to avoid the condition. You need to edit that string and remove the " AND [Notifica] = @Notifica" or simply add another string without the unrequired condition and choose at runtime which one use. Perhaps you should think to stored procedures but a better approach could be using an ORM

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using ADO.NET vs say Dapper or Entity Framework?

Comment: @mjwills because it is a legacy project and the query are done in this way

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve], including how you are executing `SELECT_USERS_FROM_AOO`.

Comment: Damien_The_Unbeliever mmm I am not sure because what happens it the @Notifica param is null? Is it searching the record where the [Notifica] field is null?

Comment: Damien provided you with what you asked for.. `My doubt is: @Notifica can be null. If this parameter value is null I want to skipe this AND condition.

ADO.NET allow to do it in some way?`

Comment: Your comment suggests that you think the table column value might be null sometimes, but if it is, then you don't search for it using `Notifica = NULL`, you use `Notifica IS NULL`. Your query as written will never (ever) find any row where Notifica column is null because no matter what you put in the parameter (null, some value etc), a row with a NULL in Notifica will always return false for this condition of the where

Comment: @CaiusJard No, this is not my problem. My problem is create a query that can skip a condition. The only mandatory parameter is the first one, the second is not mandatory, if the second parameter is null ignore the second AND condition

Comment: You probably want scenario 2 in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Scenario 1:

Your table column will sometimes be null, and you want to be able to find those. Your query needs to be:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = @parameter OR (column IS NULL and @parameter IS NULL)
```

Pass a value in the parameter to find rows where `column` is that exact value. Pass NULL in the parameters to find rows where `column` is null.

#### Scenario 2:

Your table column will sometimes be null or not, and you want to be able to return them. You want a way of passing the parameter so that sometimes the parameter is skipped (not used for search at all). Your query needs to be:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (column = @parameter OR @parameter IS NULL)
```

Pass a value to find the value. Pass NULL to skip this check (find rows that have any value of `column`, including nulls)

#### Scenario 3:

Your table column will sometimes be null or not, and you want to be able to return them. You want a way of passing the parameter so that sometimes the parameter is skipped (not used for search at all) and other times the column value can be some variable thing (including anything) matching a pattern, but not null. This is half-skipping - you can search for any non-null value. Your query needs to be:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE @parameter OR (@parameter IS NULL AND column is null)
```

Pass an value to find the value. Pass '%' to find any non null value. Pass a more refined wildcard to find just that match. Pass NULL to find only rows that have a null value in column.

#### Scenario 4:

Your table column will sometimes be null, and you want to be able to find those as well as any occurrences where the column is null. You will pass 'skip' as the parameter value to skip the check. The table column will never contain 'skip'. Your query needs to be:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE 
  column = @parameter OR column IS NULL or @parameter = 'skip'
```

Pass a value to find columns of that value or null. Pass 'skip' to skip the check

Combine the techniques if none of these meet your need. To search a column for nulls, you have to use a `column is null AND @parameter = 'some value I will pass to indicate I want nulls'` pattern

#### Remember

Nothing is ever equal to NULL, not even another null...

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE NULL=NULL --returns 0 rows.
```

Checking for nullness MUST be done with `IS NULL`.

`x = NULL` of any form, including `x = @parameter_that_is_set_to_null` is always false

Answer (score 0):

**Yes** you can do so, By using this simple technique:

```
// 1. First Your have to put Notification into a variable.
var notification = Null; // For Example Notification Parameter has null value

// 2. You Have to Write a Queries based on your requirements.
string queryWhenNotificationIsNull = "SELECT ...."; // This Query doesn't include AND Condition.

string queryWhenNotificationIsNotNull = "SELECT ... "; // This Query include AND Condition.

// 3. You have to check that the Notification Parameter is Null or Not ?
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Notification))
   // call QueryWhenNotificationIsNull ....
else
   // call QueryWhenNotificationIsNotNull ....
```

Answer (score 0):

As others noted, this is an odd way to build your SQL statements. However you can kinda do this by turning *SELECT_USERS_FROM_AOO* into a method. Then in the code where you want to use *SELECT_USERS_FROM_AOO* call the method with the actual value so it can return the desired string.

```
string SELECT_USERS_FROM_AOO(string notifica)
{
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(notifica) ?
       "SELECT * FROM PROT_UTENTI WHERE [SiglaAOO] = @SiglaAOO" :
       "SELECT * FROM PROT_UTENTI WHERE [SiglaAOO] = @SiglaAOO AND [Notifica] = @Notifica";
}
```

Example results:

```
Console.WriteLine(SELECT_USERS_FROM_AOO(string.Empty));
// SELECT * FROM PROT_UTENTI WHERE [SiglaAOO] = @SiglaAOO

Console.WriteLine(SELECT_USERS_FROM_AOO("asdf"));
// SELECT * FROM PROT_UTENTI WHERE [SiglaAOO] = @SiglaAOO AND [Notifica] = @Notifica
```